# Can I retrieve a distributed.client instance if I know its id?

Tags: python, distributed, dask, dask-distributed

With dask there is an id associated with each instance of distributed.client. Calling .id on a client will show its id. Can I retrieve a client instance if I know its id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not generally recommended, using internal implementation.

For global clients (as opposed to temporary ones), you can look in the variable `distributed.client._global_clients`. The values of this dictionary-like are the clients, and you can check each one to see if its ID matches the one you are after

```
client = [c for c in distributed.client._global_clients.values()
          if c.id == id_i_am_seeking][0]
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason I asked is because I assumed that creating too many client instances may become problematic. Is this true?

Comment: Presumably there is a limit, but I haven't heard of it being an issue.